# The right way to pass an object to fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to pass an object to fragments
when the object shouldn't or can't recreate in a fragment (e.g. `LruCache`).

Is it possible without using `static` variable?
since passing variable may not always same object

Edit:
To make it clear I don't want the object to be null when `activity` recreated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passing object to fragment you should use interface have a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

You can pass object via constructor and getter and setter also but in case of app resume object might be null that will cause `NullPointerException` on app resume.

***Edited***

If you are working with LruCache and want to share its data within fragments. I will suggest you to create a fragment without a onCreateView() method, means it will be invisible fragment. Implement a LruCache object in fragment and have getters and setters to get and set desired objects from LruCache.

Fragments have a characteristics of re-usability in contrast to a simple class. You can find a fragment by its tag.

For example: To add a fragment-

```
activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment, TAG).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

and to get a fragment-

```
activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
```

In contrast to normal class Fragment class is removed from memory only when device is in sort of memory. Whenever fragment is null you will have to re-initialize it.

To know more about its implementation details visit [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

Comment: Actually this is what I want to ask
how to prevent `LruCache` null
when `activity` recreated

Comment: what are you storing in `LruCache`?

Comment: Bitmaps which is download from network
example:
fragmentA contains cache1,
fragmentB contains cache1,
fragmentC contains cache2

if you restore cache inside fragment
there will be two copy of cache1 instead of one

Comment: Thank you
I didn't notice `Handle Configuration Changes` section in the first place